# Ipad/mobile and html encoded Jquery URL link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-encode

I have made a web app and we are using [imageflow](http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/)

And in the description for the image we have a link to another part of our website. The problem is that the href has to be html encoded or else it breaks the decription and places the url in the wrong place. Because of this it does not work on mobile or the ipad/phone.

Is there a alternitive i can use to encode instead of using $quot; for example or some type of fix i can use to get this to play nice with mobile?

```
<img src="image/img1.jpg" longdesc="setup.php" alt="&lt;strong&gt;Name1&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Birthday1&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;profile.php&quot;&gt;View Profile&lt;/a&gt; / &lt;a href=&quot;photos.php&quot;&gt;Photos&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;greenText&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Question&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;ask.php&quot;&gt;Ask them!&lt;/a&gt; " />
```

Each image is like this. The Imageflow app asks that the urls to be encoded in the alt description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few options to escape a quote:

- `&#32;`
- `&#x22;`
- `&quot;`
- `%22` (shortest one)

If possible, I recommend to change the URL to a more appropriate URL instead.

Comment: Thanks, tried it and it didnt work. Like i said if i try to do it the standard way it will break the jquery program im using

Comment: I assume that you're talking about the `alt` attribute, rather than the `href` attribute (original question)? In that case, it's obvious that html entities are required. The *only* non-entity alternative is using single quotes: `<img alt="<a href='profile.php'>..</a>" src="image.png" />`